# Finding friends while commenting,in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

In my Iphone app,when user types symbol "@" , a pop up will come and all his friends list will be shown,he can select any of the friends from that.

But now my client need to do some modifications.If a user type @, popup should not come,but when he type any letter after @,all the friends name starting with that letter should come in a popup.
Eg:- if user typed @p - pop up will come with all the friends name starting with letter P.

How to do this,I have tried something but could not make it happen
(I am getting friends list in an array while loading the view)
Now I am using

```
     - (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {

     if([string isEqualToString:@"@"])
     {
       s=1;


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
       [frndsView setCenter:CGPointMake(frndsView.center.x, frndsView.center.y-310)];
       [UIView commitAnimations];


     [commentField resignFirstResponder];
      }
     return YES;
    }
```

Comment: From contacts? You will need ns predicate to do so

Comment: Not from contacts, I get an array of friends

Comment: I answered it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

use This code on textChanged of the text

```
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *term in arryOfWordsToBeSearched) {
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",term];
        [subpredicates addObject:p];
        }

     NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
    result = (NSMutableArray*)[arryOfDummyData filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];
```

result is an array

Comment: use array of contacts in place of "arrayOfdummyData" and change this line self contains[cd] %@ according to the data source cmnt if u need help